# Utilizing mlock() in android applications

Tags: android, linux, memory-management, swap

a-swapper enables swap in android devices in which it uses the SD card as the swap space (http://code.google.com/p/a-swapper/). Can I make an application that prevents specific current running applications to be swapped into the swap space using mlock() or is there any other approach on this?

also, the busybox default applets seem to not have mlock().

Answer (score 2):

Read [mlock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html) man page. It requires root privilege or at least 
`CAP_IPC_LOCK` capability. See [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)

On most Android systems it is not easy to root them.

And `mlock` apply only to the current process virtual space (not to other processes address space). Read about [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). Consider using `/proc/` 
(see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for more) to find out about it. (Understand the output of `cat /proc/self/maps` ....)

Reading [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) should also help.

Comment: What is the current process virtual space and "other processes address space"?

Does this mean that current running processes present in RAM can't be affected by mlock()?

Comment: I added more reference. But you need to take several hours to read a lot more.